# Add code inside specific wordpress standard function

Tags: plugin-development, customization, filters

Is it possible to add a piece of code snippets inside wordpress standard function ? In my case I am developing a plugin that will trace the exact location of the caller of wp_delete_attachment method in wordpress. I can acheive that by **debug_backtrace()** but this method must be called inside the method you wish to trace. How can I acheive this without touching/ editing the wordpress core functions ?

```
function wp_delete_attachment( $post_id, $force_delete = false ) { <-- wordpress core function
global $wpdb;
  //my custom code inside wordpress core function
  $bt = debug_backtrace();
  $caller = array_shift($bt);

  die(json_encode($caller));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by hooking my function to `delete_attachment` hook, then putting the debug trace inside my function and filtering the `wp_delete_attachment`, by this I can retrieve what file and line number where the wp_delete_attachment is called.

```
add_action( 'delete_attachment', 'your_function' );
function your_function($postid) {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();

    if(is_array($trace) && !empty($trace)) {        
        foreach ($trace as $trace_value) {
            if(array_key_exists("function", $trace_value)) {
                if($trace_value['function'] == "wp_delete_attachment") {

                    echo $trace_value;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do.

If you look into the [function definition](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_attachment/#source-code), you'll notice some [do_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/):

For example:

```
do_action( 'delete_attachment', $post_id );
do_action( 'delete_post', $post_id );
do_action( 'deleted_post', $post_id );
```

These are points, called hooks in WordPress, where you can actually run your stuff. Hooks will help you to modify the core behaviour without modifying the WordPress core itself.

Let's assume you want to hook into the code before the attachment is deleted, you can then use `add_action('delete_attachement', 'yourfunction');` in your plugin or theme's `functions.php` to run any code you want.

For example:

```
add_action('delete_attachement', 'yourfunction');

function yourfunction( $post_id ){
  echo 'sample';
  die;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: I assume you're adding that only to troubleshoot something? If yes, do it and clean up afterwards.

Comment: i am developing a plugin that will log the location which portion of wordpress deleled media files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook your function to `delete_attachement` hook, but you also need to remove some extra functions that are called before calling your hooked action to reach the right caller of `wp_delete_attachment()`.

Here's a possible implementation...

```
function my_backtrace( $post_id ) {
    $bt     = debug_backtrace();
    array_shift( $bt ); // Remove reference to function
    array_shift( $bt ); // Remove reference to call_user_func_array
    array_shift( $bt ); // Remove reference to do_action
    array_shift( $bt ); // Remove reference to wp_delete_attachment
    $caller = array_shift( $bt ); // This is what called wp_delete_attachment
    die( '<pre>' . json_encode( $caller, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) . '</pre>' );
}
add_action('delete_attachement', 'my_backtrace');
```

Also you can use `json_encode( $caller, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT )` to pretty print your encoded JSON ;)

Lemme know how it works for you...

Cheers

Comment: Hi Dan,
Mark an answer as accepted when it solves your problem so that other can know that this is resolved ;)